# Где надо поставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где надо поставить запятые в предложении:
"А ведь Боря прав!"

Answer (score 1):

В этом предложении запятые не нужны.

Answer (score 1):

1. Если вы считаете, что именно Боря прав, и сообщаете об этом кому-то, то никаких запятых не нужно.
2. Если вы *обращаетесь* к Боре и сообщаете *ему*, что прав кто-то другой, тогда необходимо обособление (как обращение):
   "А ведь, Боря, прав!"

Обычно так не говорят. Лучше бы "добавить" конкретизирующее местоимение, например:
*А ведь он прав, Боря!*
Или: *А ведь, Боря, он прав!* Или: *А ведь, Боря, ты не прав!*

Answer (score 0):

**А ведь Боря прав!**

Как уже сказано, запятая в этом предложении не ставится, так как **ведь** здесь является  **усилительной частицей**.

Но тогда возникает вопрос: а почему возникло желание запятую поставить?

Дело в том, что по значению частица ***ведь*** близка к вводному слову, исторически она восходит к  глаголу ***ведать*** – знать. Можно было бы сказать: "А знаете, Боря-то прав". И объяснить, почему наконец это стало ясно.